# How Split a Large events table in google bigquery into multiple table based on event_type?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Hi I would like to split a large bigquery table (10 Billion Event Records) into multiple tables based on the event_type in the large table.

Note the events table is time/day/event_time partitioned. Further assume that it as a year of data(365 days)

let's assume the event_type=['sign-up', 'page-view']

My approach:

1. Create a new table, each for the event type
2. Run and insert job, for each event type for each day[also i will be using dml inside a python script]

My questions:

1. what load job type should i use: copy or load job?
2. can i queue the load jobs to google big query?[would it work asynchronously?]
3. would google big query process this load job in parallel?
4. Is there anything I need to do it interms of using multiprocessing inorder to speed up the process? [the load job is handled by bigquery, if i can queue in the jobs than i don't need to do any multiprocessing on the client side]

Any pointers to an efficient solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [query jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview#query_jobs) for your requirement. [Load jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data) are used to ingest data into BigQuery from GCS buckets or local files.

The quotas and limits for query jobs can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs). These quotas and limits apply to query jobs created automatically by running interactive queries, scheduled queries, and jobs submitted by using the [jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) and query-type [jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) API methods. In a project, up to 300 concurrent API requests per second per user can be made.

The query jobs that use the `jobs.insert` method will be executed asynchronously. The same can be achieved using the Python client library (as you intended) as shown below. Please refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results) for more information.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the destination table.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)

sql = """
    SELECT corpus
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    GROUP BY corpus;
"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

Since the jobs will be running concurrently, there is no need to implement explicit multiprocessing.